# two-level classification in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Data: there are 14 attributes in my dataset, 2 types of output classes.

I want to perform a 2 level classification:
Where the first classifier takes all the 14 inputs and predicts the taxonomy level (6 classes) of the learner

The second classifier takes the 14 attributes and the output of the first level to predict the mastery level (3 classes)

I tried a pipeline kind of ensemble for this two-step classification. But I am unable to get the output at the first level. Please help me with this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import preprocessing 
from sklearn import svm
names=`['Taxonomy_Level','Mastery_Level','Test_Attempts','Test_Scores','Learning_Gain','No_Questions_Remembering','No_Questions_Understanding','No_Questions_Applying','No_Questions_Analyzing','No_Questions_Evaluating','No_Questions_Creating','No_of_Hints_Used','Level_of_Assignment_Completed','Prerequisite_Concept_Completed','Learner_Taxonomy_level','Learner_Mastery_level']
print(names)`

dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/suheel/Desktop/testdataset.csv')
#print(dataset.head())                                
X = dataset.drop('Learner_Taxonomy_level', 1)
X1=X.drop('Learner_Mastery_level',1)

X2=dataset.drop('Learner_Mastery_level',1)

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 



# Encode labels in column 'species'. 
X2['Learner_Taxonomy_level']= label_encoder.fit_transform(X2['Learner_Taxonomy_level']) 

y1 = dataset['Learner_Taxonomy_level']
y2=dataset['Learner_Mastery_level']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, y1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

classifier =svm.SVC(kernel='linear') # RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)


print('Accuracy' + str(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))


###prediction for final class
map_Learner_Taxonomy_level={
    'Remember':0,
    'Apply':1,
    'Create':2,
    'Understand':3,
    'Evaluate':4,
    'Analyze':5

}

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X2, y2, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)


print('Accuracy' + str(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Comment: This setup implies that the fit of first classifier will be independent of fit of the second one (is that intended? with neural networks for example you could make them dependent). Also please post some sample data and clarify what you mean by *"But I am unable to get the output at the first level."* What is the actual problem?